# Thread stopping prematurely

Tags: c#, multithreading

Somehow my thread is stopping prematurely, while it should be alive all the time until the status becomes 4, or the thread is aborted through `.Abort()`.

Currently this is how I start my thread:

```
var thread = new Thread(() =>
{
   var t = Thread.CurrentThread;
   var cDown = new cDownloader(textBox1, textBox3.Text, this, 10);
   updateThreads(t.ThreadState + ": " + t.Name, t);
 });
 thread.Start();
```

The thread executes several functions inside the cDownloader class:

1. The constructor, cDownloader(), which sets several variables.
2. The constructor fires initLoad(), which iniates a timer, and adds an event to it.
3. The timer tick event scans a website with HtmlAgilityPack, for links with class fileThumb.
4. For every link, the event creates a new thread that downloads the file.

Somehow the thread seems to activate everything, even downloading the files, and then closes itself, whilst still running the timer, which is weird, and thus it results in an error because the current thread can't be found.

Nowhere am I calling `.Abort()` method on the current thread.

So my question is: Why is my thread stopping prematurely?

Comment: is your thread throwing exceptions?

Comment: Nothing is throwing exceptions, the program still runs, downloading all of the images found, and outputting everything to the log textbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like anything inside the thread is actually blocking. You could use an exit flag, like so:

```
var exitRequested = false;

new Thread(
() => {
  var t = Thread.CurrentThread;
  var cDown = ...
  Name = textBox1.Text;
  updateThread(...);
  while(!exitRequested)
  {
    /// keep this thread from locking up a CPU core
    t.Sleep(10);
  }

}
).Start();
```

and, later on when you want the thread to exit (when the app is closing, an `exit` button is clicked, etc)

```
exitRequested=true;
```

The loop is necessary to keep the thread from exiting early. Otherwise, when it hits the end of your lambda, it returns just like any other method.

Also note that checking `Thread.ThreadState` within the thread will usually return `ThreadState.Running`, since in order for any code in the thread method to execute, the thread has to be running. `ThreadState` is useful outside of that context.

Comment: Marking this as the answer, since this solved it! Thanks David.

Answer (score 3):

The thread will run the code in the delegate you pass it. Once that is complete the thread will terminate. Unless `updateThreads` contains a loop, the thread will terminate upon completion of the last method call in the delegate.

Comment: The class contains a loop, shouldn't that suffice for not terminating the thread?

Comment: @StefanCandan The only thing running in the thread is what you've put inside the lambda, and the methods it calls. A loop that doesn't exist in that context has no effect on the thread lifetime.

Comment: Thank you for the information, didn't know that. Quite new to threads and such. I solved it with the help of your answer, David Lively

Answer (score 3):

Part of the problem is the following line

```
Name = this.textBox1.Text;
```

The UI cannot be accessed from background threads and will throw an exception.  Hence this line is throwing after the `cDownloader` class is created and subsequently kills the thread.  You need to move the UI access out of the background thread or appropriately marshal access back to the UI thread.

Comment: I removed that, it still did the same.

Comment: @StefanCandan you are also passing UI elements to the `cDownloader` class.  Are they accessed inside there?  Have you tried debugging which exceptions enabled?  That should point you directly to which line is throwing